Изменение памяти в других процессах Android NDK
Я пишу библиотеку на c++ для своего приложения на Android, я изменяю поведение другой библиотеке, которая есть в моём apk, при изменении target sdk с 28 на 33, данный код на 5 строке приводит к вылету, как решить данную проблему? Переписать libGTASA я не могу.
char* PLAYERS_REALLOC = nullptr;
    PLAYERS_REALLOC = ((char* (*)(uint32_t))(g_libGTASA + 0x179B40))(404 * 257 * sizeof(char));
    memset(PLAYERS_REALLOC, 0, 404 * 257);
    unProtect(g_libGTASA + 0x5D021C);
    *(char**)(g_libGTASA + 0x5D021C) = PLAYERS_REALLOC;

        void unProtect(uintptr_t ptr, size_t dwSize)
    {
        if (dwSize)
        {
            auto* to_page = (unsigned char*)((unsigned int)(ptr) & 0xFFFFF000);
            size_t page_size = 0;
    
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < dwSize; ++i)
            {
                page_size = j * 4096;
                if (&((unsigned char*)(ptr))[i] >= &to_page[page_size])
                    ++j;
            }
    
            mprotect(to_page, page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
            return;
        }
    }


Стать рутом и напрямую, через /dev/mem?

Я же это приложение хочу в массы пустить, будет не здорово, если каждый пользователь 14 андроид будет должен рутировать его.

Ну, вы наверное поняли, что про рута это была шутка. Конечно, я не пишу под Андроид (и далек от мира прораммирования игр), но исходя из самых общих соображений,  не уверен, что модифицировать конкретную версию либы (по константным смещениям) это вообще здравая идея. Наверное тут нужен в принципе какой-то другой подход.

По другому никак
